# How do I copy contents of a file and concatenate it into a new file?

Tags: text-processing

I have to make new files that contain the original file contents twice and then concatenate it line by line. For example:

`File 1`:

```
ABCDABCD
ABCDABCD
```

to `New File 1`:

```
ABCDABCD
ABCDABCD
ABCDABCD
ABCDABCD
```

Edit: I was able to get an answer to this question, however I was informed that this was the wrong place to post it. Thank you for the help and sorry for the incorrect location for posting it.

Comment: I could not understand exactly. I want to more detail. That's mean is as following?
FILE1:
1111111
2222222
new file1:
1111111
1111111
2222222
2222222

Comment: **I'm voting to reopen this question** because most text processing questions are on topic here, especially if they can be solved with a little shell scripting.

Comment: My answer (preliminarily as a comment): `cat 'File 1' 'File 1' > 'New File '` or if 'File 1' and 'New File 1' point to the same file `sponge < 'File 1' >> 'File 1'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't concatenate a file into itself, but you can concatenate and send an echo:

```
echo `cat file1` >> file1
```

Everytime you do this, the contents on file1 would be duplicated.

And, anyway, this is not the place for this question.

Comment: Oh ok, well thank you and I'm sorry. Where should I post questions like this next time? Thank you for informing me.

Comment: I just tried this and it just had cat file1 in the new file 1. There was no duplication.

Comment: Well, you have to create first a file1 with some content...

Comment: Or use "back ticks" -- i.e., a `\` ` -- instead of single quotation marks...

Comment: Ah, it was the back tick that I got wrong. Thank you both darent and @jon

Answer (score 2):

I think, this is what you looking for

```sh
while read -r line; do echo "$line"; echo "$line"; done < file1 | sed 'N;s/\n/ /' > file2
```

While loop would helps to duplicate all the lines from  `file1` and the `sed` command will combine the two consecutive lines into one.

Comment: this reduplicates the input on the same line...

Comment: i think, that's op looking for.Duplicate,combine the duplicate lines and save it.

Comment: Oh, maybe you're right!  The example 'file 2', then, is very misleading.  (Will delete my answer once it's confirmed.)

Comment: Question is unclear, i can't figure out what the op is trying to say.

Comment: `printf '%s\n' "$line"` would actually be better in case `$line` happens to coincide with an option of `echo`.

Comment: I believe that only `while read -r line; do printf '%s %s\n' "$line" "$line"  ; done < file1 > file2` should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

What language are you trying to use?

Python:

```
#opens file in read mode
first_file=open("myfile.txt", 'r')
#uses x to grab entire file contents
x=first_file.read()
#Concatenate 2 times
x=x*2
#Close your first file
first_file.close()
#Open new file in write mode
new_file=open("myfile2.txt", 'w')
#Write the Concatenated text
new_file.write(x)
#Close the file
new_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` (per what your question is saying):

```
awk '{printf ("%s %s\n", $0, $0)}' file1 >newfile
```

Based on your given input and expexted output, you could do:

```
awk '1;1' file1 >newfile
```